# ASP.NET MVC: Two output file names resolved to the same output path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild, resources

I have an ASP.NET MVC project (SomeProject) with Resources folder in the root folder.
Inside of my resources folder I have such folders and files: PageA\Index.resx and PageB\Index.resx.

After building the project I should have such classes in code: SomeProject.Resources.PageA.Index and SomeProject.Resources.PageB.Index.

However when I try to build, I get such error: Two output file names resolved to the same output path: .....\Index.resources

Is there a way to workaround this problem?

P.S. Please do not offer to rename PageB\Index.resx to something else, as this is not the desired solution.